.onKeyPress fails to update bound variables in the .repeat phase
.onKeyPress action closures exhibit correct behaviour when modifying a State variable defined with the view it operates on.
If however, the closure attempts to update a bound variable (defined with @Binding) then the variable is only ever updated once, and does not continue to fire when the corresponding key is held down.
Apple feedback filed: FB14751737

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var doubleValue: Double = 1.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Focus the value and press and hold either <- left arrow  or  right arrow ->")
            HStack{ Text("Repeats don't work: "); DoesntWork(doubleValue: $doubleValue) }
        }.monospaced()
    }
}

struct DoesntWork: View {
    @Binding var doubleValue: Double
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(doubleValue)")
            .focusable()
            .onKeyPress( keys: [.leftArrow,.rightArrow], phases: [.down, .repeat] ) {keyPress in
                    if keyPress.key == .leftArrow  { doubleValue -= 1} else { doubleValue += 1} // only works once - ignores repeats
                return .handled
            }
    }
}

Bug confirmed on:
macOS 14.6.1 and Xcode 16-beta-4 &
macOS 15.1 beta and Xcode 16.1 beta (16B5001e)

Could not replicate the issue using MacOS 15 and Xcode 16 beta-4,
tested on MacOS 15 and MacCatalyst.
Both methods worked. Using DispatchQueue.main.async instead of Task also worked.
Maybe it was a bug that has been fixed. What system are you with and targeting?

I'm using macOS 14.6.1 and Xcode 16-beta-4.  Good to know that it's fixed in Sequoia. At least I can code around it for now. Thanks for the update

Issue still exists on Sequoia 15.1 beta 2, and with Xcode beta 16.1

Strangely enough, wrapping the update to the bound variable in a Task closure restores the expected behaviour:

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var doubleValue: Double = 1.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Focus one value and press and hold either <- left arrow  or  right arrow ->")
            HStack{ Text("Bound variable; repeats don't work: "); DoesntWork(doubleValue: $doubleValue) }
            HStack{ Text("Using Task, repeats work: "); Works(doubleValue: $doubleValue) }
            HStack{ Text("Local state, repeats work: "); AlsoWorks() }
        }.monospaced()
    }
}

struct DoesntWork: View {
    @Binding var doubleValue: Double
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(doubleValue)")
            .focusable()
            .onKeyPress( keys: [.leftArrow,.rightArrow], phases: [.down, .repeat] ) {keyPress in
                    if keyPress.key == .leftArrow  { doubleValue -= 1} else { doubleValue += 1} // only works once - ignores repeats
                return .handled
            }
    }
}
/// Very hacky fix to the apparent bug attempting to modify a binding from an onKeyPress event.
struct Works: View {
    @Binding var doubleValue: Double
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(doubleValue)")
            .focusable()
            .onKeyPress( keys: [.leftArrow,.rightArrow], phases: [.down, .repeat] ) { keyPress in
                Task { // why does this make it work??
                    if keyPress.key == .leftArrow  { doubleValue -= 1} else { doubleValue += 1}
                }
                return .handled
            }
    }
}
struct AlsoWorks: View {
    @State var doubleValue: Double = 1
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(doubleValue)")
            .focusable()
            .onKeyPress( keys: [.leftArrow,.rightArrow], phases: [.down, .repeat] ) { keyPress in
                if keyPress.key == .leftArrow  { doubleValue -= 1} else { doubleValue += 1}
                return .handled
            }
    }
}


Agree that this looks like a bug.
Here are two other workarounds.
1. Change the result returned by the closure.
Currently you are returning .handled. According to the documentation:

The action consumed the event, preventing dispatch from continuing

This also seems to be preventing repeats. If you change it to .ignored then repeat works. However, an undesirable side effect is that there is then a warning sound, presumably because the system thinks the event was not handled.
2. Use an .onChange handler to update the binding
Following from your comment that it works when a local state variable is used instead of a binding, you could change it to operate this way and then update the binding in an .onChange handler:
struct Works: View {
    @Binding var doubleValue: Double
    @State private var localValue: Double

    init(doubleValue: Binding<Double>) {
        self._doubleValue = doubleValue
        self._localValue = State(initialValue: doubleValue.wrappedValue)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(localValue)")
            .focusable()
            .onKeyPress(
                keys: [.leftArrow, .rightArrow],
                phases: [.down, .repeat]
            ) { keyPress in
                localValue += (keyPress.key == .leftArrow ? -1 : 1)
                return .handled
            }
            .onChange(of: localValue) { oldVal, newVal in
                doubleValue = newVal
            }
    }
}


It is definitely incorrect behaviour. Returning .handled works fine if you operate on a locally defined State variable:  struct AlsoWorks: View {     @State var doubleValue: Double = 1     var body: some View {         Text("\(doubleValue)")             .focusable()             .onKeyPress( keys: [.leftArrow,.rightArrow], phases: [.down, .repeat] ) { keyPress in                 if keyPress.key == .leftArrow  { doubleValue -= 1} else { doubleValue += 1}                 return .handled             }     } }

Agree that it looks like a bug. Added another workaround, based on your comment.

side note: you can merge .onChange and .init ( or .onAppear )  by using the .onChange(of: Equatable, initial: true) version of the modifier, or you can replace with .task(id: localValue)..    It's baffling to me how this bug has arisen .. what could be stopping an update to a bound variable that is fixed by such hackery? Are there other places where a bound variable operates differently to a state variable ?

@Disco The onChange is detecting changes to localValue, so I'm not sure how it can be used to initialise localValue from doubleValue. If it was an onChange for doubleValue then yes, initial: true could be used.

yes. read too quickly :)
